# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `..........` must be length ... (the group size) or one, not

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Date.Start = as.Date(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-10")),
                   Date.End = as.Date(c("2017-09-10", "2020-09-15")),
                   Number.of.Years = c(3, 6),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#  Date.Start   Date.End Number.of.Years
#1 2015-09-01 2017-09-10               3
#2 2015-09-10 2020-09-15               6
```

I'm trying to "blow up" the dataframe with one row per year to:

```
#  Date.Start   Date.End Number.of.Years  Year
#1 2015-09-01 2017-09-10               3  2015
#1 2015-09-01 2017-09-10               3  2016
#1 2015-09-01 2017-09-10               3  2017
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2015
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2016
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2017
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2018
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2019
#2 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6  2020
```

So I tried the following:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

expandRows(mydf, "Number.of.Years", drop = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(Date.Start, Date.End) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq(year(first(Date.Start)),
                    year(first(Date.End)),
                    by = 1))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Date` must be length 6 (the group size) or one, not 4
```

What is going wrong in the above code?

If I try to change it to the number of days (from another post on stackoverflow) it works fine though:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Date.Start = as.Date(c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-10")),
                   Date.End = as.Date(c("2015-09-03", "2015-09-15")),
                   Number.of.Days = c(3, 6),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

expandRows(mydf, "Number.of.Days", drop = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(Date.Start, Date.End) %>%
  mutate(Date = seq(first(Date.Start),
                    first(Date.End),
                    by = 1))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Date.Start, Date.End [2]
#  Date.Start Date.End   Number.of.Days Date      
#  <date>     <date>              <dbl> <date>    
#1 2015-09-01 2015-09-03              3 2015-09-01
#2 2015-09-01 2015-09-03              3 2015-09-02
#3 2015-09-01 2015-09-03              3 2015-09-03
#4 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-10
#5 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-11
#6 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-12
#7 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-13
#8 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-14
#9 2015-09-10 2015-09-15              6 2015-09-15
```

Comment: what's the difference between the working code and your code?

Comment: @josemz Thanks, for noticing. Changed it now.

Comment: The problem is that there aren't 6 years between 2020 and 2017, only 4, which is what the error message says. Notice how in your example there are 3 days between 1 and 3 and 6 days between 10 and 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have different years, which is why it does not work at your first case (2015 Vs 2020 - You have 6 rows to fill and you are trying to put the seq between 2015 - 2020 hence the error), then we can use the group size `n()` to create the sequence, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

expandRows(mydf, "Number.of.Years", drop = FALSE) %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(!duplicated(paste0(Date.Start, Date.End)))) %>% 
   mutate(Date = seq(first(Date.Start), (first(Date.Start)+n()-1), by = 1))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 5
> # Groups:   grp [2]
>   Date.Start Date.End   Number.of.Years   grp Date      
>   <date>     <date>               <dbl> <int> <date>    
> 1 2015-09-01 2015-09-03               3     1 2015-09-01
> 2 2015-09-01 2015-09-03               3     1 2015-09-02
> 3 2015-09-01 2015-09-03               3     1 2015-09-03
> 4 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-10
> 5 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-11
> 6 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-12
> 7 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-13
> 8 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-14
> 9 2017-09-10 2020-09-15               6     2 2017-09-15
> ```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant. I updated/improved my post now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. It seemed to be an issue with quality of the data where I was not aware of.

So, if you do a group_by, you have to be certain that there are no duplicate rows with the samen feature, but with different date.start and/or date.end.